# c# group list items that have part of the same text inside

Tags: c#

I  have this list listemailsMsgs that have items like this:

```
email1@hotmail.com;mensagem1;assunto1
email2@hotmail.com;mensagem1;assunto1
email3@hotmail.com;mensagem2;assunto2
```

The first two items have different emails, but the messages are the same.
The third item has a different email and a different message.

I am having a hard time finding a way to group the first two items into just one, like this:

```
email1@hotmail.com;email2@hotmail.com;mensagem1;assunto1
```

Does anyone have any idea of how to do that?

Comment: What have you tried? I'd probably start by splitting each row into an array of each part and then compare the items in each array. Not particularly elegent but a simple brute force approach.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, try to convert the given values into a c# model, so that it will be easy for you to solve this kind of problem.

In the mentioned question, the item value contains the three sections, so create an Item class to represent it.

```
    public class Item
    {
        public string EmailAddress { get; }
        public string FirstMessageField { get; }
        public string SecondMessageField { get; }

        public Item(string message)
        {
            var result = message.Split(';');
            EmailAddress = result[0];
            FirstMessageField = result[1];
            SecondMessageField = result[2];
        }
    }
```

Then, convert all your given string values into a List of Item.

```
        var input = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item("email1@hotmail.com;mensagem1;assunto1"),
            new Item("email2@hotmail.com;mensagem1;assunto1"),
            new Item("email3@hotmail.com;mensagem2;assunto2")
        };
```

Finally, use LINQ operations to group your values based on the message fields:

```
        var output = input
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.FirstMessageField, x.SecondMessageField })
            .Select(x =>
            {
                var emailAddresses = string.Join(';', x.Select(y => y.EmailAddress).ToArray());
                return $"{emailAddresses};{x.Key.FirstMessageField};{x.Key.SecondMessageField}";
            })
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group by message and the row parts have the ';' as delimiter, then you can do the following:

```
var grouped = list.GroupBy(x=>x.Key.Split(new string[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[2]);
```